Changing specific color using color drop
I have been texture painting an object on a UV map. The problem is that now when I see the final result, I’m not happy with some of the colors that I have been using.
Is there some Way that I Can change only certain colors without having to re paint on top of everything all over again ?
Is it possible to color drop and change only one color, just like in procreate ?
It’s a pity if we have to re paint all of it, if we are unhappy with only parts of it.

Did you solve this on your own?

I ended up using the Ucupaint addon. Thank you for taking your time to help me out.

Fill Threshold is a setting in the Image Editor only for the Fill Tool. Set it low enough that your desired color is dropped only within the range of your previous color pixels. This is not an available feature in the Fill Tool in the 3D View for Texture Paint.

